# R8: does not type check and will be assumed to be unreachable

Tags: android, log4j, slf4j, obfuscation, android-r8

When enabling `android.enableR8.fullMode=true` I get the following warning:

```
AGPBI: {
    "kind": "warning",
    "text": "The method `void org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<clinit>()`
             does not type check and will be assumed to be unreachable.",
    "sources": [{}],
    "tool": "R8"
}
```

How to explicity keep `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<clinit>()` with R8? `android.enableR8.fullMode=false` (the default setting) is not an acceptable workaround, even if the `static` initializer `<clinit>` wouldn't get optimized alike that. The code being stripped is [this](https://github.com/apache/commons-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/Log4JLogger.java#L77):

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Static Initializer.
//
// Note that this must come after the static variable declarations
// otherwise initialiser expressions associated with those variables
// will override any settings done here.
//
// Verify that log4j is available, and that it is version 1.2.
// If an ExceptionInInitializerError is generated, then LogFactoryImpl
// will treat that as meaning that the appropriate underlying logging
// library is just not present - if discovery is in progress then
// discovery will continue.
// ------------------------------------------------------------

static {
    if (!Priority.class.isAssignableFrom(Level.class)) {
        // nope, this is log4j 1.3, so force an ExceptionInInitializerError
        throw new InstantiationError("Log4J 1.2 not available");
    }

    // Releases of log4j1.2 >= 1.2.12 have Priority.TRACE available, earlier
    // versions do not. If TRACE is not available, then we have to map
    // calls to Log.trace(...) onto the DEBUG level.

    Priority _traceLevel;
    try {
        _traceLevel = (Priority) Level.class.getDeclaredField("TRACE").get(null);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // ok, trace not available
        _traceLevel = Level.DEBUG;
    }
    traceLevel = _traceLevel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended, and the details of the analysis can be seen in the http://issuetracker.google.com/146478391.

A possible solution is also present these, which involves making sure that the relationship between Level and Priority (Level extends Priority) is known to R8 compilation.

Comment: That's the issue, however "if the log4j jar is added to the input the type checker error should go away" is kind of unclear, because the dependency is [org.slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j) (which means, that likely there isn't any `log4j.jar` present).

Comment: Could you please explain the exact dependencies and keep rules for slf4j you use? Then I can try to do a real reproduction. For the referenced issue I just extracted `log4j/org/apache/log4j/Priority.class` and `log4j/org/apache/log4j/Level.class` from `log4j.jar` and added them as input classes as well.